# Find the recently added tag or find the tags that are new to Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion

I was looking into the Stack Overflow API, to find the tags that are newly added to Stack Overflow.

But I could not form a URL to meet my requirement.

I found [this URL](http://www.bryceboe.com/2011/02/21/using-stackoverflows-api-to-find-the-top-web-frameworks/), but the author has not listed the API call URL he used. Also he was trying to get the top frameworks.

But I would like to get the (say, 10 - 20) tags newly added to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Questions about the Stack Overflow API should be directed to the [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com/) site.